# Clear Graphics Object to Black or other RGB

Tags: c#, graphics

I am a rank beginner in C#.  I am currently using this code:

```
        objGraphics.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
```

What I want to do is Clear this object to black (or some other RGB color), and I'm stumped as to how to replace the SystemColors.Control with, preferably, an RGB color spec.  I'd probably want to clear to black most of the time.  Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Gene, I apologize for that.  StackOverflow won't let me rate answers, even though I have this ID.  I'll try to figure out what's wrong with my registration.  Any tips?

Comment: It's got nothing to do with rating answers.  Click the check mark next to a good answer.  Green = accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
objGraphics.Clear(Color.Black);
```

or

```
objGraphics.Clear(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));
```

Comment: Easy!  Thanks!  StackOverflow won't let me rate answers, so I apologize for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Color black = Color.FromName("Black");
objGraphics.Clear(black);
```